# can you explain why compile time error in the below code

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

why im getting errors in the code given below....

```
#include <stdio.h>
    void foo(int*);
    int main()
    {
        int i = 10;
        foo((&i)++);(in this line error shows like this) //error: lvalue required as increment operand
    }
    void foo(int *p)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *p);
    }
```

Comment: When asking about an error please show the exact and complete error msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Member access operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access):

> The address-of operator produces the non-lvalue address of its operand, suitable for initializing a pointer to the type of the operand.

And from [Increment/decrement operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_incdec):

> The operand expr of both prefix and postfix increment or decrement must be a modifiable lvalue of integer type (including _Bool and enums), real floating type, or a pointer type.

Simply put the `&` operator does not produce an appropriate object for the `++` operator.